# Integrating admob with Android which is using actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, admob, build.gradle

I want to integrate admob to my application.

Currently I am having difficulties to setup admob sdk with Buid Gradile in Android studio.

> Buid.Gradle content:

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
}
```

Gradle file Github link: [Build.Gradle](https://github.com/arminha/worldclockwidget/blob/master/worldclockwidget/build.gradle)

Instructions I followed - https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en-GB#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk

However I am strucking at step  -

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'

I am getting the following error (attached image).

[image: error snap]

Not sure which library to download. My application is using -

> com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlok.

Which is a old library. I want to continue with that one. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried clicking on `install Respository and sync project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at bottom of your gradle file

Also add

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
```

Comment: thanks the problem is solved. But my application is crashing  at actionbarsherlok. My build.gradle is-
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" {
         minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19

Comment: add the crash log